# How do I implement the unstarred vspace option in the solution environment in exam class?

Tags: overleaf, exam, vspace

I understand that the exam class has an option to use `\unstarredvspace` so that the space will be deleted if it occurs at the top of a page.  Right now the default is a `\vspace*`  such as `\begin{solution}[4cm]`.  The manual says that I can change to the optional argument to `\unstarredvspace` but I don't know how to do that. If I place the `\vspace` option right after the question, print answers will leave that vertical space before printing the solution box which I don't want.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
% \printanswers
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question This is the first question
\begin{solution}[20cm]

This is the solution part
\vspace{12cm}
hello
\end{solution}
\question This is the 2nd question
\begin{solution}[10cm]

This is the solution part
\vspace{9cm}
hello
\end{solution}

\question This is the 3rd question
\begin{solution}[14cm]

This is the solution part
\vspace{9cm}
hello
\end{solution}

\question This is the 4th question%%%%see how there is space at the top of the page?
\vspace{9cm}
\begin{solution}

This is the solution part
\vspace{9cm}
hello
\end{solution}
\question This is the 5th question
\vspace{9cm}%%%This works but only if I know that question 5 will be the first question that overflows to the next page. 
\begin{solution}

This is the solution part
\vspace{9cm}
hello
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

In summary, I'm looking to delete space at the top of a page (like a `\vspace`) but as the option in the solution environment if possible.  Anyhow, I'm looking to ensure there is no wasted space at the top of a new page, no matter which question it occurs.  I would like to do this without placing a `\vspace` after every question because when I `\printanswers` there is the unwanted vspace before the solution.  If there is a more efficient way to delete the unwanted space at the top of a page, please let me know.

Also I"m using overleaf and it seems to cause an error in placing `\unstarredvspace` in the preamble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put   `\unstarredvspace` in the preamble.

==> Needs  `exam.cls    2021/02/26 Version 2.7` (at this time Overleaf is using 2017/12/17 Version 2.603 and will give an error) .

> `\unstarredvspace`  changes the  solution environment so that, *when*
> *solutions are not being printed*, any optional space reserved for is
> inserted with `\vspace{amount}`

With your code (and using  any other space the  after the 5th question `\vspace{15cm}` to avoid any guessing) you get five pages and the space before the questions 3 and 4.

[image: e]

Using   `\unstarredvspace` the output has three pages. Now the space before the question 4 is only the reserved by the solution to question 3 and questions 3 and 5 start at the top of the page.

[image: f]

This is the code. Note the blank line before every `\vspace{`, needed to produce the space.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
 %\printanswers 

 \unstarredvspace % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is the first question
        \begin{solution}[20cm]
            
            This is the solution part
            
            \vspace{12cm}
            hello
        \end{solution}
        \question This is the 2nd question
        \begin{solution}[10cm]
            
            This is the solution part
            
            \vspace{9cm}
            hello
        \end{solution}
        
        \question This is the 3rd question
        \begin{solution}[14cm]
            
            This is the solution part
            
            \vspace{9cm}
            hello
        \end{solution}
        
        \question This is the 4th question%%%%see how there is space at the top of the page?
        \vspace{9cm}
        \begin{solution}[12cm]              
            This is the solution part
            
            \vspace{9cm}
            hello
        \end{solution}
        \question This is the 5th question
        \vspace{15cm}
        \begin{solution}            
            This is the solution part
            
            \vspace{9cm}
            hello
        \end{solution}
    \end{questions}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I am using Overleaf and putting `\unstarredvspace` in the preamble causes an error.

Comment: @E.Yu Needs  `exam.cls    2021/02/26 Version 2.7` . Ask their support staff. They are using  2017/12/17 Version 2.603.